# Swift: How to understand that downloaded image is empty?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing

I downloading image with kingfisher, but sometimes image exist, but empty.

Example: [Sample Image](https://socialboardsbproduction.blob.core.windows.net/123/7ac2d246-9a4a-4550-8500-4b59533c3ba0.png)
How can I detect such images?

My downloading method:

```
func downloadFrom(link: String, contentMode mode: UIView.ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit, rounded: Bool = false, loader: IndicatorType = .none) {
        self.kf.indicatorType = loader
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else {
            return
        }
        let img = self.image

        if(rounded) {
            let roundedProcessor = RoundCornerImageProcessor(cornerRadius: 100, targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), roundingCorners: .all, backgroundColor: nil)
            self.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: img, options: [.processor(roundedProcessor)], completionHandler: {
                (image, error, cacheType, imageUrl) in

                if (error == nil) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
                        if (self.contentMode != UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit) {
                            self.contentMode = mode
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        } else {
            self.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: img, completionHandler: {
                (image, error, cacheType, imageUrl) in

                if (error == nil) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
                        if (self.contentMode != UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit) {
                            self.contentMode = mode
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: TRY : In completionHandler, check image size.

Comment: Can you provide some more info, please? How to check it?

Comment: Above `if (error == nil)` do `print(image)` , check whether it is nil or not and also check `image.size`.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/np97m5 - checking code. http://prntscr.com/np97u4 - result. Unfortunately, every image is not nil and has a size :( @dahiya_boy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following code, Check image size after getting an image from the server. If the file size is 0 then the image is empty.

```
self.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: img, options: [.processor(roundedProcessor)], completionHandler: {
                (image, error, cacheType, imageUrl) in

  if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
     let bytes = imageData.count
        if  bytes > 0 {
            //getting image successfully
        }else{
            //Image size is 0 (image is empty)
        }
  }else{
    //Not getting image
  }
})
```

Comment: OP just commented that "Unfortunately, every image is not nil and has a size"

Comment: yes, perfect that's why I have suggested to check the image size.

Comment: No, they always have a `size > 0`. Try `curl -o image.png https://socialboardsbproduction.blob.core.windows.net/123/7ac2d246-9a4a-4550-8500-4b59533c3ba0.png && ls -lh image.png`. You'll see that, even thought image is empty, the size is 1.3K

Comment: I can check "bytes > 5000" at least. Never seen smaller picture with user avatar ) Thanks, checking...

Comment: @AtulParmar yeeees, thanks, Atul, it's working!!! Just changed "if  bytes > 0" to "bytes > 5000". Thanks a lot! And thanks to regina_fallangi too! ))

Comment: Happy that it worked for you. For me the `bytes` for https://socialboardsbproduction.blob.core.windows.net/123/7ac2d246-9a4a-4550-8500-4b59533c3ba0.png amount to 886, while copy-pasting this code.